# On-the-nose commutative cup product $\Longrightarrow$ characteristic $0$?

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, cup-product, differential-graded-algebras

I was discussing with a student today the nature of the non-commutativity of cup-product at the level of cochains.  In trying to explain what happens, I came up with the following statement.

> **Theorem.**
>   Fix a commutative ring $R$.
>   Suppose $F:\mathrm{Top}^{\mathrm{op}}\to \mathrm{cDGA}_R$ is a contravariant functor 
>   from spaces to commutative DGAs over $R$, such that $X\mapsto H^*(F(X))$ is ordinary 
>   cohomology with coefficents in $R$.  Then $R$ contains $\mathbb{Q}$ as a subring.

I'm pretty sure this "Theorem" is true.  But I don't have a proof at hand.

The question is: does anyone have a proof, or know of one in the literature?  I'm particularly interested in seeing a proof which is relatively "elementary", in the sense of not requiring much more heavy machinery than is needed in order to make the statement.

*Added.*  Tyler points out in his answer that this can't be true as stated.  We should add a hypothesis, such as: F takes homotopy pushouts of spaces to homotopy pullbacks of chain complexes.

Answer (score 6):

Your theorem needs at least one further assumption.  Otherwise, we can let F be the functor on spaces sending $X$ to the commutative DGA $H^*(X;R)$, with zero differential.

I'm not sure what statement to add.  The thing I initially wanted to write is that your functor should take homotopy pushouts to homotopy pullbacks.  However, commutative DGAs aren't closed under homotopy pullback.

EDIT: Let's suppose you make this assumption.  Take the diagram $* \leftarrow \mathbb{CP}^\infty \rightarrow *$, form the homotopy pushout $\Sigma \mathbb{CP}^\infty$, and apply your functor $F$ to the associated square pushout diagram.  You get a commutative square of commutative differential graded algebras, which is in particular a commutative square of $E_\infty$-algebras.  The category of $E_\infty$-algebras has homotopy pullbacks, and so you can construct by this method a weak equivalence $F(\Sigma \mathbb{CP}^\infty) \rightarrow P$ of $E_\infty$-algebras, where $P$ is the homotopy pullback.

However, in any characteristic the Steenrod operations are stable operations and an invariant of weak equivalence of $E_\infty$-algebras.  If $pR = 0$, the element $x \in H^2(F(\mathbb{CP}^\infty))$ supports nonzero power operations (namely, powers) at any prime, and so the associated element
$$\sigma x \in H^3(P) \cong H^3(F(\Sigma \mathbb{CP}^\infty))$$
would also support nonzero power operations.  But for commutative DGAs those operations are automatically zero.

Ideally one could make this for more general $R$ where $p$ is not invertible using a secondary operation and $B\mathbb{Z}/p$ instead, but the kids were up early and I'm too tired to figure out how right now.

Comment: Excellent point!  And we don't need homotopy pullbacks for dgas; it's enough that we can talk about homotopy pullbacks of the underlying chain complexes of abelian groups.

Answer (score 3):

It seems to be known at least to Thom, Sullivan, Swan, Cartan and Miller (1960's). I do not have a precise reference, but do see [Cartan's Theories Cohomologiques](http://www.digizeitschriften.de/dms/img/?PPN=PPN356556735_0035&DMDID=dmdlog30)

Comment: That's a nice article, though I'm not seeing anything like my theorem.  I guess my question can be reduced to one about Cartan's *theorie cohomologique* (=certain kind of simplicial DGA): namely, to prove that a commutative *theorie cohomologique* must contain the rationals.

Comment: Here is a better reference: Theorem 2 on page 32 (due to Cenkl and Porter) says that the coefficient ring R for a commutative theorie cohomologique must satisfy squares are divisible by 2. See  
 Cenkl's paper http://projecteuclid.org/euclid.pjm/1102647247 